# Get post category as a separate string and url

Tags: posts, categories, loop, post-meta

I need to figure out how to get post category as a string and link, both separate from each other.
So the return would be something like:

Uncategorized 
http://link-to-the-category.com

however both should be separate, because I need to put them in different parts of my markup.

Comment: review http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

Answer (score 1):

First you have to find the category ID, which can be done easily with the function `get_the_category()`.

To get the slug, use: `$catID = get_the_category(); $catSlug = $catID->slug`.

To get the link: `$catLink = get_category_link($catID)`.